# View PDF image from link in Google Drive in Appsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have linked images to my App using links located in google Drive, the images are displayed without problems in the APP but when I want the data to be reflected in a PDF report the links are shown as broken.
How can I place, embed or place these images in a PDF document?

I followed the following explanation and it worked fine for the App but not for the PDF.

[In App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOwcW.png)

[In PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqBRz.png)

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. Please share it so we can see how you are going about implementing this.